# How to execute multiple queries through BigQuery Operators in Apache Airflow DAG through Google Composer?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

I need to execute multiple queries through single BigQuery operator inside my DAG which is implemented through Google Composer. I will have many Operators in the DAG and each Operator needs to execute multiple queries sequentially. I tried giving a list of queries to BigQueryInsertJobOperator but it executes only the first query in the list and ignores rest. It also does not give any error. I am trying with BigQueryInsertJobOperator.

I can not use the trick to combine all the queries in a single string as my 2nd or 3rd queries can have Declare statements which will fail if I combine multiple queries in a single string variable. Also, if I run the Operator in loop then how can I set the dependency as I will have many operators and each operator will have multiple queries.

Comment: The list of queries are different in each operator in the loop or are the same but with different parameters ?

Comment: @Mazlum, for each operator if 3 queries are there then 2 queries will be same but with dynamic values for few parameters and 1 query will be specific to that Operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `DAG` with the following structure :

```
project
     dag_folder
          queries
              object1 
                    query.sql
              object2  
                    query.sql
```

And then in your DAG, you can use this kind of code :

```py
import os

import airflow
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator
from jinja2 import Template


def get_jinja_template(file_path: str) -> Template:
    with open(file_path) as fp:
        return Template(fp.read())


with airflow.DAG(
        "your_dag",
        default_args=your_args,
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    # You can configure this list for your DAG, for example with Airflow variables or elsewhere of
    # you prefer
    your_objects = [
        'object1',
        'object2'
    ]

    dag_folder = os.getenv("DAGS_FOLDER")

    query_operators = []
    for obj in your_objects:
        query_path = f'{dag_folder}/your_dag_folder/{obj}/query.sql'

        query = get_jinja_template(query_path).render(
            project_id='project',
            param2='param2'
        )

        execute_query = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
            task_id='truncate_team_stat_staging_table',
            configuration={
                "query": {
                    "query": query,
                    "useLegacySql": False,
                }
            },
            location='EU'
        )

        query_operators.append(execute_query)

    chain(*query_operators)
```

Each query file can contains multiple queries, example :

```sql
SELECT ... FROM `{{project_id}}.dataset.table where element = '{{param2}}'....;
SELECT ... FROM table2 where ....;
```

- I used a structure with a list of objects on the `queries` folder
- In the `DAG`, I configured this list of object
- I loop on this list
- For each object, I load the associated query from the `DAG` structure and `queries` folder : `queries/object/query.sql`
- I render this query with `Jinja2` template and params
- I pass this query on the `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`
- I create a list of `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`
- Each query file can contains multiple SQL queries
- The `DAG` will execute each `BigQueryInsertJobOperator` operator and queries by object sequentially via the `chain` operator

I hope this solution will help.

Comment: Thanks @Mazlum, let me go through it. Just for information: the queries .sql are not single statements. They comprise a set of queries with Declare, Set and if-else kind of statements.

Comment: And also, for each operator the queries should run in sequence and when all the queries are executed sequentially, then next Operator should get executed (again with multiple queries to be executed in sequence)

Comment: Ok for the execution in sequence, I am going to edit my answer as soon as possible. There is an Airflow operator called `chain`.

Comment: ok @Mazlum, let me know once you update your answer for execution in sequence part.

Comment: I updated my answer with the queries by object executed sequentially using the `chain` operator.

Comment: Thanks @mazlum. How are the variables (or params) mentioned inside sql file ? {variablename} or some other way for the above code of yours ?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example with params. It corresponds to Jinja template with params.

Comment: Sorry, I could not update here earlier, Apologies. Your answer helped a lot, tweaked it as per requirement as the requirement also changed later on. But your piece would have worked as well. Thanks & Apologies again.

Comment: No problem, you’re welcome. I am glad my answer helped you. Can you mark it as solved please ?